# C#: Custom paint scroll on scrollable panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollable, custom-painting

Could someone provide an example about how to custom paint the scrollbar in a scrollable panel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still want the automatic scrolling behavior of contained controls -- it's only the appearance of the scroll bar you want to change?  The long way is to fully re-implement the scrolling on a non-scrollable Panel; hopefully someone knows a shorter way.

Comment: I doubt it, there's no custom draw support for the window scroll bar.

Comment: Yea, the only way to do this is to create custom scroll bars and deal with 'docking', scrolling, and drawing. It's generally not done with Windows common controls (which is what Winforms uses) because the work outways the benefits. WPF is the better choice for this.